# Manga where man reincarnates into his own novel where his familiar is a white tiger and the main hero that he invented uses a king slime

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

He reincarnates and finds himself in the novel he wrote and he knows where all the hidden stuff is because he wrote it and he doesn't impede the main character and occasionally helps him out. His familiar is a white tiger and his character is bald and the tiger licks his head for hair. The hero he wrote has a king slime or something legendary like that.

Comment: *Forced To Become The Villainous Son In Law*?

Answer (score 3):

Could this be *Tamers* (AKA *Spirit Ranger* AKA *Yu Ling Shi*)?

The main character is reincarnated into his own manhua, is bald and has a white tiger companion.

[image]